# Copy to tmux copy buffer using command line

Tags: vim, tmux

I use tmux to copy text while in copy-mode often, but what I'd like to do is copy text using command line instead of entering copy-mode.

For example, when I'm in vim directly on my mac computer, I like to select a line with `V`, then pipe that to the system clipboard with by pressing `:`, which then gives the `'<,'>`, meaning, take the currently highlighted vim text, and then `w ! pbcopy`. Pipe the highlighted vim text to system clipboard. This is useful when the line is too long to render so that tmux's copy-mode can "see" it, and I don't want to `set wrap` in vim.

I'd like to do the same for tmux, like, if this were a thing:

`$ echo "some text" | tmux copy-buffer`

Or, after highlighting a line with `V` in vim:

`:'<,'>w ! tmux copy-buffer`

Alas, I couldn't find anything in `man tmux` that suggested I could do this. Anyone know how?

Comment: Since your use case is from within Vim, you might be interested in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1647220/524058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want

```
tmux load-buffer -
```

Comment: Thank you! From within vim, this is how I'm able to highlight a very long line and write it to the tmux copy buffer: `:'<,'>w ! cat | tmux load-buffer -`. Perhaps a useless use of `cat`, but I'm happy. Also, from terminal, `echo "some text" | tmux load-buffer -` works as expected.